# Thesis cover formatting

Tags: formatting, logos, parbox

I need to put on the cover of my work: a picture, the name of the university, and another picture (logo). But the figures are one below the other (I need everything in the same line). I'm trying the command below, but I'm not getting it.

```
\def\logos{
     {\parbox{0cm}{\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{logo-unicamp.pdf}}}
      {\parbox{\textwidth}
      {
        \noindent
         \centering{
          \large \MakeUppercase{\@UNICAMP}\\
                  \@FT}
      }
      }
 {\parbox{0cm}{\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{logotipos/LOGO-EQ.jpg}}}
}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: For one you probably should not set the parboxes to have these width.

Comment: See the link for the template:
https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-graduation-work-masters-dissertation-or-doctoral-thesis-for-school-of-technology-unicamp/rhznqbkjvpcr

Comment: @JurandiLeão Many of us don't have, or want, Overleaf accounts. Make a genuine attempt to create a MWE.